# Unable to change user agent on iOS below 11 in webview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the following code:

```
    let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
    url_request.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    webView.loadRequest(url_request)
```

I get this in for example iPhone 6s 9.3, iPhone SE 10.0 etc while it works perfectly in iPhone 8 11.4 (tested on simulators). I am unable to figure out how to resolve this issue. Help is much appreciated.

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the user agent for the app in the user defaults, maybe the web view is checking this flag and seeing that it's different from what you sent on the request.
`UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"])`